# RootApproximant for a function

Tags: equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation

`DSolve` yield this rather lengthy solution

```
-(1/(2 Sqrt[3]))(\[Sqrt]((256 + x^4 - 
       16 (-4096 + 768 x^2 + 816 x^4 + x^6 + 
          24 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[x^4 (-4096 + 768 x^2 + 384 x^4 + x^6)])^(1/3)
         + (-4096 + 768 x^2 + 816 x^4 + x^6 + 
         24 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[x^4 (-4096 + 768 x^2 + 384 x^4 + x^6)])^(2/3)
        - 2 x^2 (16 + (-4096 + 768 x^2 + 816 x^4 + x^6 + 
            24 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[x^4 (-4096 + 768 x^2 + 384 x^4 + x^6)])^(1/3)
         ))/(x^2 (-4096 + 768 x^2 + 816 x^4 + x^6 + 
         24 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[x^4 (-4096 + 768 x^2 + 384 x^4 + x^6)])^( 1/3)
      )))
```

I know that for any $x>0$ it can be represented as a root of a 6th-order polynomial. The question is how to find this polynomial in terms of $x$.

Comment: What did you solve for? Quite sure that your code isn't the complete result of `DSolve`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann What is written in the post is a function $y(x)$, which was obtained by DSolve. I want to write the relation between `y` and `x` in the form of a polynomial `p[x,y]==0`. The goal is to find the polynomial.

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear. And the polynom is up to order 6 in x and y.

Comment: The polynomial is of the 6th order in `x` as follows from `RootApproximant`. The order with respect to `y` is probably lower, I have now way to know.

Comment: I think you are fooling yourself. First, depending on x,  RootApproximant gives polynomials with degree>6. Second how can you infer from RootApproximant the degree of the polynomial? RootApproximant gives a different poly for different x, but you are looking for a single poly. Then, plotting your function, it does not look if there are real  roots.

Comment: @DanielHuber maybe you put too low precision, or, maybe I copy-pasted wrong. For what value of x do you get order>6?

Comment: @DanielHuber if a function satisfies a parametrized polynomial equation, then for random values of the parameter there will be a maximal number of roots. So pick a random rational value for `x`, take `MinimalPolynomial`, and if degree is six (it will be) then that's the degree to expect generically, and the highest degree one can attain.

Comment: E.g. Let t be your expression. Then RootApproximant[t /. x -> 1.2] gives an 8th degree poly.

Comment: @DanielHuber Try this one `RootApproximant[N[h /. {x -> 6/5}, 100]]`. You need more precision for `RootApproximant` to work.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau Hello Daniel, nice to hear from you.I think I miss something here. Let t be the above expression. Then RootApproximant[t /. x -> 1.2] returns 8th degree poly. But  RootApproximant[t /. x -> 12/10] returns a 13th degree poly. It looks like the answer depends on the precision of the number.

Comment: @DanielHuber No surprise there. It is an approximation, and trades coefficient size against degree. The way to get the correct polynomial is `In[10]:= InputForm[MinimalPolynomial[ee /. x -> 12/10]]
Out[10]//InputForm=
-75 + 209*#1^2 + 472*#1^4 + 144*#1^6 &`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by `GroebnerBasis`.

```
ee = -(1/(2 Sqrt[3])) (\[Sqrt]((256 + x^4 - 
         16 (-4096 + 768 x^2 + 816 x^4 + x^6 + 
             24 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[
               x^4 (-4096 + 768 x^2 + 384 x^4 + x^6)])^(1/
             3) + (-4096 + 768 x^2 + 816 x^4 + x^6 + 
            24 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[
              x^4 (-4096 + 768 x^2 + 384 x^4 + x^6)])^(2/3) - 
         2 x^2 (16 + (-4096 + 768 x^2 + 816 x^4 + x^6 + 
               24 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[
                 x^4 (-4096 + 768 x^2 + 384 x^4 + x^6)])^(1/
               3)))/(x^2 (-4096 + 768 x^2 + 816 x^4 + x^6 + 
            24 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[
              x^4 (-4096 + 768 x^2 + 384 x^4 + x^6)])^(1/3))));

xypoly = First@GroebnerBasis[y - ee, x]

(* Out[517]= -12 + 32 y^2 + x^2 y^2 + 64 y^4 + 8 x^2 y^4 + 16 x^2 y^6 *)
```

The proof that this works is a trivial application of a common mathematical principle, which, loosely worded, is "Look, just take my word for it".

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I have suspected it is a one-liner. Very nice.

Comment: @yarchik Much as I like compliments, next time please wait until after I post my response so you don't, like, scare me.

Comment: Beyond "Look, just take my word for it":  `ee == (y /. Solve[xypoly == 0 && x != 0, y][[1]]) // Simplify` evaluates to `True`